# Interactive maps with overlay on mouse over

Tags: javascript, php, css, maps

I have stumbled upon the world of javascripting and css just moments ago and I have been given a project by my adviser on interactive maps.

The problem is I don't have a clue on how i should start this project and one thing I want to know and find out is that How can I make an interactive map with just javascript , css and a little bit of php or cms?

I found these sites: 
http://www.lglab.co.uk/usaSVG/advanced/index.html
http://edition.cnn.com/ELECTION/2012/ecalculator#?battleground

both are related to what I'm about to do.

I want to know how I could be able to code an interactive map like those in the examples above with a little bit of customization and without paying for tools

Comment: I would suggest doing a bunch of tutorials before jumping into a project like this.
Get a feel for the language, then start with something simple. That said, the highlighting of the states that's happening there could be done with CSS.

Comment: @Cerbrus I have already practiced a lot of CSS styles and highlighting on hover but i don't quite get how i could put up an overlay on mouse over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn SVG - the only way you can really make event-driven polygons.

See: http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/

Answer (score 2):

Try OpenLayers [ http://openlayers.org/ ] - its a free and open source javascript mapping toolkit. Check the examples for interaction and events and all that.

You need your data in some vector format - GeoJSON, GML - something like that. Then write a whole bunch of javascript to add layers to the base map and handle events.

Other Open Source Javascript map toolkits are available (eg Leaflet) but OpenLayers is the heavyweight master.

Answer (score 1):

You can use geoJSON for this. 
see http://palewi.re/posts/2012/03/26/leaflet-recipe-hover-events-features-and-polygons/